# Alternatives to 'collecting coins'

Tags: game-design, game-mechanics

In the generic mario style game you collect coins as you go along your primary adventure (i.e. get to other side of the map). They usually offer generic additions like the ability to get extra lives and +score. Other games like platformers use them additionally as currency for skins etc. Donkey kong 64 its bananas and they do something similar, only sometimes its linked to progression itself (banana medals). These all relate to collecting the same kind of item where touching them is all you need to do.

Are there any examples or ideas applying the concept of coins (things you collect in a gameworld as you go along) to a more interesting game mechanic? For example in shooters I suppose it would be collecting weapons. In my case I'm specifically interested in what might be added to a top-down 2d game. Whether they should be optional asides (mario coins) or more important to progression (banana-medals unlocking maps)...I would look for alternatives more to the optional side.

Looking more to the collection side of the mechanic. There's alot you could do with the money, but don't focus so much on that part.

Comment: what kind of 2D top down game?  (shooter, strategy, etc) =)

Comment: Why do you want to add a collectible? If your game design does not need a collectible, why bother artificially adding some?

Comment: As the examples in your question demonstrate, collectibles like coins serve many different roles in many different games. So depending on your game's needs and the kind of experience you want to create, different alternatives might be more or less appropriate. Unfortunately, as it stands, we don't know anything about your game and what you're trying to accomplish, so we can't suggest suitable coin/collectible mechanics to achieve it. [Try following the guidance in the game-design tag info](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/game-design/info), editing your question to focus it on your game.